# Using git for managing a book's example source code: how to propagate changes?

Tags: git

I'm writing a technical book. It has an example project that I build up throughout the book. Using git in the regular way is no problem of course.

But when a new version of the software comes out: that could mean a small change somewhere right in the beginning of the code... A small change in the initial generated code. How do I make that change in, say, the second changeset and have it propagate throughout the examples?

Or I might decide to change a variable name in chapter two. That *has* to propagate in all the following chapters' examples.

There's probably a git trick I can use to pull this off, so I'm all ears for a useful tip.

Comment: Did you consider git-scribe? https://github.com/schacon/git-scribe

Comment: No, I didn't look at git-scribe. I've done now, but I'm not going to use it. In the python world, sphinx (http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) is the default documentation tool, so I'm using that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're arranging the Git repository so that a "commit" corresponds to a "chapter" (or something similar). Assume that each revision is tagged with a tag name `chapter-x` for the following:

First, go back to the chapter you want to change:

```
git checkout chapter-2
```

Make the change to the code, and commit it, amending the original `chapter-2` commit:

```
# edit file here
git add test.c
git commit --amend
```

Update the `chapter-2` tag to point to the new, amended commit:

```
git tag chapter-2
```

Switch back to the end of your book:

```
git checkout master
```

and finally, rebase against the *new* `chapter-2`:

```
git rebase chapter-2
```

This will rewrite chapters 3 and beyond so that they are based off the change you made in chapter 2. Note that you may encounter a lot of conflicts doing this (especially if, in later chapters, you modify code involving whatever you changed in chapter 2). Git can help, but unfortunately it can't do *all* the work for you.

Comment: In the chapters I have now, I have around 20 commits per chapter :-) Is the tagging an essential part of getting rebase to work? I might have to have several tags per chapter that way. (It will still save me lots of work, though).

Comment: No, you don't need tags, you can identify the commits any way you like (tags just made it easier for my explanation). You can use raw SHA1 commit identifiers if you like.

Comment: Works like a charm (also with SHA1 IDs). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, since you're trying to manage the steps you walk the user through as git commits you essentially have a two dimensional history. On one dimension you have the normal git history as you update your project for new versions of the software, fix bugs in the examples, etc. On a separate dimension you have the steps that you walk the reader through.

```
O-->O-->O-->O-->O  Third edition
^   ^   ^   ^   ^
|   |   |   |   |
O-->O-->O-->O-->O  Second edition
^   ^   ^   ^   ^
|   |   |   |   |
O-->O-->O-->O-->O  First edition

^   ^   ^   ^   ^
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   Add Step 5
|   |   |   Add Step 4
|   |   Add Step 3
|   Add Step 2
Step 1
```

Each modification you walk the user through should be a branch. To update an example, check out that branch, make, and commit your modification. Then to ensure that whatever changes you made in that example are reflected in later steps, you should, in order, checkout the branch for each later example, and **merge** in the branch you just updated. Rebasing would be a mistake because that discards history relationships along the book edition dimension and only maintains the history of the steps you walk reader through.

Say you have to update step 1 and there's a bug fix you need to make in step 3

```
git checkout step_1
# update step_1
git commit -a -m "update initialization example for v9.0"
git checkout step_2
git merge step_1
git checkout step_3
# bug fix
git commit -a -m "fix bug reported by reader..."
git merge step_2
git checkout step_4
git merge step_3
git checkout step_5
git merge step_4
git tag fourth_edition


       >X-->X-->X  Fourth edition
      / ^   ^   ^
     /  |   |   |
A-->X   B   |   |
^   ^   ^   |   |
|   |   |   |   |
O-->O-->O-->O-->O  Third edition
^   ^   ^   ^   ^
|   |   |   |   |
O-->O-->O-->O-->O  Second edition
^   ^   ^   ^   ^
|   |   |   |   |
O-->O-->O-->O-->O  First edition
```

commit B is the bug fix and commit A is the update to step 1. Xs are merging in updates from previous steps.

Comment: I'm already taking the code examples in the book directly from the example source code. They're separate code repositories. My question is about the separate code repository. How to propagate a small change in chapter two's code in the 250 revisions of that same code that come after that... :-)

Comment: Are you trying to manage those 250 revisions as git commits? As in, git is managing both whatever revisions you make to the example project as you fix bugs in the example code, update it for new versions of the software, etc. _and_ the changes you walk the reader through in the text?

Comment: I'm managing the example code as one single continuous project. All the commits slowly build up the example. I'll have tags for all the intermediary steps that I want to show in my book. I'll have a script extract every tag into a separate directory and extract it in the book from there. That also gives me a directory I can zip up so that readers have all the examples.

Answer (score 1):

To modify history in this way, the general tool is `git rebase -i`. There is one caveat: you cannot use it to rewrite the *very first* commit, as you must specify a commit to start at (which is excluded).

Run `git rebase -i startcommit`; this will bring up an editor listing commits. Change the command to "edit" on the commit you need to modify, then save and exit.

Rebase will then “stop for amending” the commit you specified; make your necessary code changes, apply them with `git commit --amend`, or commit them as new additional commits if appropriate. Once you have finished the changes, do `git rebase --continue`; this will apply all of the preexisting “later” commits, and stop if you need to resolve a conflict.

I strongly recommend reviewing the history afterward using a viewer such as `gitk` to make sure that the whole picture is still what you want; you might also want to compare the final version to the old final version, which would be `git diff master@{1} master` (or whatever branch name you use).